# How I can change password in Azure AD

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, social-authentication

I am using Microsoft azure ad a authentication. When I am trying to change the user password with graph api it will give me an error

[image]

I have also set permission that is required for password change, but then it will also not work

[image]
I have wrote code in node.js with like this

```
const changePassword = {
            currentPassword: ctx.request.body.currentPassword,
            newPassword: ctx.request.body.newPassword
        };
        const client = createAuthenticated.createAuthenticatedClient();
        await client.api('/me/changePassword').post(changePassword);
```

Comment: After adding the API permission you need to do grant admin consent for your tenant.

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT yes, It was granted that is required for change Directory.AccessAsUser.All

Comment: Give Directory.ReadWriteAll as well.

Comment: Because you are chagning the user password it should have write permission as well.

Comment: Granted all permission but not working, same error

Comment: Hope from wherever you are reading **ctx.request.body.currentPassword** and **ctx.request.body.currentPassword** should pass as in string. For reference you can follow this [documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-changepassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript)

Comment: Yes I am reading as a string ,even I tried with hardcode values same as mentioned in document

Answer (score 0):

The changing password api can only support delegate permission, it has been indicated in [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-changepassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), and it also appeared in your error message.

Delegate api permission means you can't use client credential flow to generate access token/credential to call this api, you can only use such as ropc flow or auth code flow to generate the access token.

I think you've read [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-changepassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#request) to call the api, but you didn't choose a correct authentication provider. If your app is a website which required user to sign in, then you may choose [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Javascript#authorization-code-provider). But pls note, the [client-credential-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Javascript#client-credentials-provider) is not suitable for this scenario.

=======================Update====================

The html+js code in my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70575713/15581227) provides a sample which integrate msal to  let user sign in and generate access token for calling graph api.

Change `AzureMgmtScops` value to `scopes:["Directory.AccessAsUser.All"]` then it will return you an access token with this permission, then pls use this token to send a post request like this, I think you can then finish your task. But this way will not change your server side, it's suitable for the structure which is frontend-backend separated.

[image]

Comment: Then how i can implement that, can you help on that ?

Comment: The link I provided in the answer contained sample code, if you can follow the document and test it first? I didn't have a complete sample for your scenario.

Comment: yes Tiny, I have test that with your flow. but i am not able generate delegated authentication flow for a client

Comment: you can generate the delegated authentication flow, then what's  the problem now?

Comment: met issue about generate the authProvider? https://i.stack.imgur.com/94xhv.png

Comment: how i validate for user suppose i want to change any one password first i need pass his credential in option, how i will do that means email and password

Comment: After you integrate msal in your application, I mean the code provided in the document, then your app should have a popup window to let user sign in, then `<AUTH_CODE_FROM_QUERY_PARAMETERS>` should appear in the popup window's url, then pls sent it to your nodejs server, and this can make you get the `authProvider`. Then the question left is let users enter the old password and the new password, sending passwords to your nodejs project. Now you've got all the elements to call change password api. I misunderstood your requirement?