# Get JWT for checking permissions

Tags: jwt, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0

I'm working on a .NET 6.0 MVC app and trying to implement a function to send emails using Microsoft Graph. The app is used internally at my company and is using Windows Authentication. I don't have any experience with the "nitty gritty" of authentication. I have implemented a solution for Microsoft Graph found at the following link that seems to be close to working except I receive an error that "The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood": [How to send email from any one email using Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70771954/how-to-send-email-from-any-one-email-using-microsoft-graph/70780395#70780395)

My Azure AD admin doesn't really have any experience with setting this kind of thing up, so the `Mail.Send` permissions may not be correct, and I'd like to check the token. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get it so I can enter it into jwt.ms/jwt.io. This is what I've tried so far, but I'm getting the error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANTNAME.onmicrosoft.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token' from origin 'http://localhost:XXXXX' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
var token;

function requestToken() {

$.ajax({
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANTNAME.onmicrosoft.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token",     
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "data": {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id ": "IDHERE",     
        "client_secret": "SECRETHERE", 
        "scope ": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        token = response.access_token;
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = token;
    }

})
```

Am I on the right track at all for implementing Graph with Windows Authentication, and if so, how can I get this token in order to check it? Thanks!

Comment: need to use msal to avoid cors policy, you can't send ajax request to that url to generate token. see my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70575713/15581227) may help you generate access token.

Comment: @TinyWang When I try this, I get another error attempting to get the token: "ClientAuthError: User login is required. For silent calls, request must contain either sid or login_hint". I tried using the signIn function included, but that also results in an error ("response_type 'id_token' is not enabled for the application."). In order for this to work, do I need be using something other that Windows Authentication?

Comment: `response_type 'id_token' is not enabled for the application` maybe you need to go to azure portal->azure ad->your application->Authentication-> pick ID tokens and access tokens then click save.

Comment: @TinyWang That worked. I got the token now. I see `"scp": "Mail.Send User.Read profile openid email"` in there, but I still can't send email. I got added as owner of the app and can make some changes to it now in Azure AD, so hopefully that means things can move faster than before.

Comment: There's a good write up about this exact topic here that explains how to use either the JWT or Powershell Library to get information about assigned roles/scope s to your graph app: 
https://medium.com/@easy365/how-to-check-the-permissions-of-your-microsoft-graph-application-via-jwt-0e0e7d6af68d